# How can let form submit the value of input inside shadow root of custom HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html

I created a custom HTML input element like follow:

```html
<html>
<script>
    class TestInput extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
        super();
        var shadow = this.attachShadow({mode:'open'});
        var cinput = document.createElement('input');
        cinput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        cinput.setAttribute('name', 'test');
        cinput.setAttribute('value', 'test');
        shadow.append(cinput);
        this.cinput = cinput;

        }
    }
customElements.define('test-input', TestInput);
</script>
<body>
<form action="/test">
  <test-input></test-input>
  <input type="submit"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I used spring to receive the form parameters, I get nothing. How can I submit the form with the value of input inside the shadow root?

Comment: Click on `<>` in question editor and turn this into a runnable snippet that others can quickly copy and test with right here in the page

Comment: @charlietfl I turned it into a runnable sinppet. Thanks.

Comment: The `form.elements` collection completely ignores the input in the custom element and only returns the submit button. Must it be in a custom element? Or could you put the whole form in it? I've never worked with form controls this way so just tossing around ideas right now

Comment: @charlietfl it must be in a custom element and I can't put the whole form in it. Because this is a requirement of my project.

Comment: Have you seen this article? https://web.dev/more-capable-form-controls/

Comment: @NickParsons This article solved my problem! Thanks!

Comment: @NickParsons could you please add the article as an answer and the owner (Michael Tsai) to accept it? Sometimes people miss the comments on a question.

Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 3):

Per [web.dev/more-capable-form-controls](https://web.dev/more-capable-form-controls/) linked in the comments by [@nick-parsons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5648954/nick-parsons).

---

First you want to add [`formAssociated`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-face-example) static prop to the class of your custom-element and assign it `true` in order to turn your custom-element into a *[form-associated custom element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#form-associated-custom-element)* like so:

```js
class MyCustomElem extends HTMLElement {
  static formAssociated = true;
  //...
}
```

Then you want to call [HTMLElement.attachInternals()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/attachInternals) on your custom-element

> can be done in the `constructor()` like
>
> `let internals = this.attachInternals()`

in order to use [ElementInternals.setFormValue()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementInternals/setFormValue) returned from `attachInternals()`.

Finally, you would use `setFormValue()` to update the value that your custom-element will submit to the outer form, probably called through an `addEventListener()`.

---

Modifying the example from the question:

```html
<html>
<script>
    class TestInput extends HTMLElement {

      // make element form-associated
      static formAssociated = true;

      constructor() {
        super();
        var shadow = this.attachShadow({mode:'open'});
        var cinput = document.createElement('input');
        cinput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        cinput.setAttribute('name', 'test');
        cinput.setAttribute('value', 'test');
        shadow.append(cinput);
        this.cinput = cinput;

        // get form-related abilities
        this.internals = this.attachInternals();
        this.cinput.addEventListener("input",
          (event) => {
            let value = event.textContent
            // update value that form has access to
            this.internals.setFormValue(value)
          })

        }
    }
customElements.define('test-input', TestInput);
</script>
<body>
<form action="/test">
  <test-input></test-input>
  <input type="submit"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. but I made my won solution by creating an input inside the `shadow Host` and outside the `shadow Root`. that input's value will be updated whenever the one inside `shadow Root` value change.

shadow Host => `<test-input name='email'>`
shadow Root => appears in the runtime like this `#shadow-root (open)`

you should use `connectedCallback` to bind `addEventListner` with the new input.

and finally, you can use normal `querySelector` to point out `shadow Host` and `shadow Root` and the value of input inside.
but that way you are accessing the `shadow Root` by JS and you can't get the value directly by submitting the form.

the other option as mentioned by creating new input and update its value within `connectedCallback` and that way you can use `FormData` or submit the form normally and then you will recive the value based on the `name attribute`

```js
let form = document.getElementById('frm');

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    // stop form submission
    event.preventDefault();
  
    alert('get value from shadowRoot: ' + form.querySelector('test-input').shadowRoot.querySelector('input').value);
  
    alert('get value of binded elemnet within shadowHost: ' + form.email.value);

});

let shadow;
class TestInput extends HTMLElement {

      constructor() {
        super();
        shadow = this.attachShadow({mode:'open'});
        var cinput = document.createElement('input');
        cinput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        cinput.setAttribute('value', 'test');
        shadow.append(cinput);
        this.cinput = cinput;

        var inputToBind = document.createElement('input');
        let name = this.getAttribute('name');
        inputToBind.setAttribute('name', name);
        inputToBind.setAttribute('value', cinput.value);
        this.appendChild(inputToBind);
        }
    

connectedCallback() {

        this.cinput.addEventListener("input",
          (event) => {
          let value = event.target.value;
          this.querySelector('input').setAttribute('value', value);
          })
  }
  
}
customElements.define('test-input', TestInput);
```

```html
<form id='frm'>
  <test-input name='email'>
    <!-- here where to append new input which will bind to form based on given name -->
  </test-input>
  <button type="submit">submit</input>
</form>
```